# Intermediate YAML template, resources repository's ref and parameters "Internal error reading the template. Expected a scalar,a sequence,or a mapping"

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

[Azure Pipelines docs state that we can use template expressions in `resources.repositories` `repository.ref` argument.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-repositories-repository?view=azure-pipelines)

It already works in some parent template, but using `$(Build.SourceBranchName)` instead of template expressions. In some child template, the template expression produces the error `"Internal error reading the template. Expected a scalar, a sequence, or a mapping"`. BTW, if I use template expressions in parent template, I get there the same error.

Alternatively, if I use `$(Build.SourceBranchName)`, child template throws error `"Could not get the latest source version for repository xxxx-dotnet-solution hosted on Azure Repos using ref $(Build.SourceBranchName).` (in this case, Azure Pipelines won't parse the variable).

I can't figure out how to fix this problem.

Here's the affected child template:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: buildConfiguration
    type: string
    values: [Debug, Release]

  - name: api
    type: string

  - name: solutionLocation
    type: string

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: xxxx-apis-parent-templates
      name: xxxx-dotnet-solution
      type: git
      ref: ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranchName'] }}

extends:
  template: .az-devops-cicd/templates/aks.yaml@xxxx-apis-parent-templates
  parameters:
    solutionLocation: ${{ parameters.solutionLocation }}
    projectRepository: xxxxxx-apis
    projectBaseDir: ${{ parameters.solutionLocation }}/${{ parameters.api }}/
    projectName: XXXX.${{ parameters.solutionLocation }}.Apis.${{ parameters.api }}
    buildConfiguration: ${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}
```